# Why I can pass a pointer in a method and "free" the memory inside?

Tags: c, pointers, free

I have always read that in order to modify any variable inside a function in C, you must pass a pointer to that variable.

If I want to delete a particular element in a linked list, and I do something like:

```
int DeleteElement(element **head, element *deleteMe)
{
  free(deleteMe);
  return 1;
}
```

Why am I able to free that deleteMe and that gets reflected outside the DeleteElement function? Isn't the deleteMe another thing inside the function?

Thanks

Comment: Because u need to pass the same address to free as that returned by malloc. `free` does not erase the contents at the memory. It merely marks the blocks free for reutilization.

Comment: `free(deleteMe)` does not modify `deleteMe`. There is no contradiction.

Comment: Think about how can the `free` function can free a pointer considering it's passed a pointer exactly like your `DeleteElement` function.

Answer (score 0):

You're not writing anything to the pointer `deleteMe`. You're using it (in a read-only way) to determine what object to free (the object it points to).

Comment: But if I can free it, it means I have access to the object it points to. Why I don't have access to modify its value??

Comment: The value of the pointer remains the same after you free it. However it is no longer useful, and most/all further use of it would invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: @R.. So, if I want for example to test the pointer against NULL to determine that no memory has been allocated, does that mean that I would have to explicitly write NULL to the pointer after freeing the memory?

Comment: @m4l490n: Yes, for exactly the same reason that demolishing a building doesn't remove its address from business cards it was printed on. The reason a pointer is called a pointer is that it's a value that tells where something else is found. It's up to you to manage whether that value is meaningful or not.

Answer (score 0):

You pass a **pointer to an address** (the name or variable use to provide that pointer does not matter). The memory block of that address is freed. Therefore, it is also freed 'outside' the `DeleteElement` function.

Comment: But then why if I want to modify the content of that address I need to pass a pointer to it? If I can free it from inside it means I can access to it, so it would mean I can modify it, right?

Comment: Yes, you could (instead of freeing the memory) also modify it, eg using `deleteMe[0].xyz = 123` (obviously replacing `xyz` with a valid field name and `123` with a valid value)